# Adding images from s3 to Quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to include images from an s3 bucket in Quicksight "custom visual content" without making the images public to the whole world [just to our private Quicksight dashboard].  I allowed Quicksight to access that bucket.  Below is my bucket policy [still with no success].  I found this QuickSight documentation: "To embed internal URLs or URLs that you own, you might need to set them to be opened in an IFrame."  How can I set an image in s3 to be opened in an IFrame?  Is embedding images from s3 bucket to Quicksight possible at all [without making them public]?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "quicksight.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::quicksightbucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::quicksightbucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with QuickSight, but it is likely that the HTML is simply referencing the image directly in S3 (use View Source to confirm). This would mean that it is your browser that is requesting the object from S3 rather than QuickSight requesting the object, so the above policy would not be relevant. I doubt that QuickSight could generate pre-signed URLs (which is a way of providing temporary access to private objects in S3), so your remaining option might be to use complex filenames and make the objects public (but hard to 'guess').